# CSS Background and border of outer div

Tags: css, html, background, border

I have a div for gallery that contains other divs(each on has an image).In the outer div i set backgournd and border but nothing happens... I know the problem is that inner divs cointains only  tags and nothing else. How can i work this arround without setting fixed width??
*All tags where closed even before.I copied part of my code, sorry for the misunderstanding!
*Someone said to set overflow and it worked! Thank You!(post was deleted and didnt saw who was!
Thanks all for the answers!

```
<div class="gallerybox">
     <div class="img">
         <a href="#" onclick="OpenNewWindow('#', 550, 413); return true;"><img src="#" width="140" class="border1" alt="Click..."/></a>
     </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS.

```css
.gallerybox {
    background:#CCC;
    border:#000;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Thanks :D

Comment: your code works OK, but you're missing end tag for your outer div. http://jsfiddle.net/fjSGs/

Comment: i have closed all the tags i didnt copied all my code :)

Comment: It can be difficult to diagnose a situation when not all of the contextual information is present.  Could you post the appropriate code, or give a link to what you have already?

Comment: I edited my first post, thanks all for the answers again! :)

Answer (score 4):

The background is working correctly. Your border issue can be fixed by assigning it a specific width and style.

For example:

```
border: 1px solid #000;
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mQQ2A/2/

Answer (score 2):

Hi you should be using background-color and border-color attributes when specifying only the color of those.

```css
.gallerybox {
    background-color:#CCC;
    border-color:#000;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you didnt set anything for the border but its color and radius:

```
border:#ccc;
```

Should be:

```
border:solid 1px #ccc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you close `div.gallarybox`.  Right now it's open.  When I tried it and closed it, I found it functioning like one would expect.

http://jsfiddle.net/6rGxw/